# What type of join for linking table to get results matching both values?

Tags: sql, join

I just stated learning sql and I've been studying the join types from help pages like w3s but I'm not understanding which join type would give me results to something like this:

I have a many to many relationship between students and the courses they are enrolled in, via a linking table:

```
SC
----
StudentId
CourseID
```

I want to get all studentIds who are enrolled in Math (CourseId: 1) and English (CourseId: 2). It's obviously kind of trivial to get students where CourseID = 1 OR CourseId = 2 but how do I join it so I can get matches for CourseId = 1 AND CourseId = 2 (unique matches if possible so I don't have each student twice in the results).

Comment: `select * from students s where exists ( ...) and exists ( ...)` (fill in the blanks)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I did try this and I kept getting union'd results (students in Math OR English). I think the AND between the exists just appends the results of the second part to the results from the first part and returns both as one list? However maybe I did it wrong.. Sorry.

Comment: No, `AND` means Boolean AND :: both should exist.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong then: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b6354/27

I expected only three results (# of students in both classes), however I get 5 results (students in one or the other).

Comment: You do not need to join in the exists() subquery, only test if a {studentid, courseid} tuple exists, where studentid refers to the outer query. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select StudentId 
  from SC
 where CourseID in (1,2)
 group by StudentId 
having count(*) = 2

select SC1.StudentId 
  from SC as SC1
  join SC as SC2
    on SC1 CourseID = 1
   and SC2 CourseID = 2

    select StudentId 
      from SC
     where CourseID = 1 
 intersect
    select StudentId 
      from SC
     where CourseID = 2
```

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of the interset command, I saw union but that didn't seem applicable. I like the middle one where you essentially make two copies of the table and join there, I would have never thought of something like that!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM students st
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM sc
    WHERE sc.studentID = st.Id
    AND sc.courseID = 13
    )
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM sc
    WHERE sc.studentID = st.Id
    AND sc.courseID = 42
    )
    ;
```